# Angular 2 - Trying to add row class on every other loop iteration

Tags: angular, materialize

Im using Materialize.css with Angular 2x and Id like there to be a row for every 2 card columns. Its currently displaying the first and third cars from the json file. Would like it to show the 1st and 2nd car and break into a new row and show 3rd and 4th. Appreciate any help.

html component

```
 <app-car  *ngFor="let car of cars"  [car]="car">
      <div   *ngIf="car.id%2 !== 0" [ngClass]='"row"'> 
       <div class="card col l6"  >
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="assets/images/{{ car.image }}.jpg" alt="car">
        </div>
        <div class="caption center">
          <div *ngIf="!car.showDetails" >
            <h4>
              <span class="card-content">
                {{ car.name }}
              </span>
            </h4>
            <h5>     
                {{ car.price | currency:'USD':true }}
            </h5>

            <button 
              class="btn waves-effect waves-lights blue darken-1"
              *ngIf="!car.showDetails"
              (click)="car.showDetails = !car.showDetails">
             Show Speed
            </button>

          </div>

          <div *ngIf="car.showDetails">
            <div  >
              <p class="card-action">{{ car.speed }}</p>

             <button
                class=" btn waves-effect waves-light"
                (click)="car.showDetails = !car.showDetails">
                Close
              </button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </app-car>
```

json file
              [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "KOENIGSEGG AGERA R",
        "price": 1700000,
        "speed": "273 mph",
        "image":"car-1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "HENNESSEY VENOM GT",
        "price": 410500,
        "speed": "270 mph",
        "image":"car-2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "BUGATTI VEYRON SUPER SPORT",
        "price": 395000,
        "speed": "273 mph",
        "image":"car-3"
      },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "9FF GT9-R",
        "price": 1170000,
        "speed": "257 MPH",
        "image":"car-4"
      }
    ]

Whats displaying
[image: cars app]

Solved: I ended up adding a row outside of the loop and added a height and min-height to the image and content area.

[image: cars]

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you run your JSON through a reduce to group the cars in each row, like this:

```
    this.carRows = [
      { "id": 1, "name": "KOENIGSEGG AGERA R", "price": 1700000, "speed": "273 mph", "image":"car-1" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "HENNESSEY VENOM GT", "price": 410500,"speed": "270 mph", "image":"car-2" },
      { "id": 3, "name": "BUGATTI VEYRON SUPER SPORT", "price": 395000, "speed": "273 mph", "image":"car-3" },
      { "id": 4, "name": "9FF GT9-R", "price": 1170000, "speed": "257 MPH", "image":"car-4" }
    ]
    // attach this reduce wherever your data is coming from
    .reduce((memo, car) => {
      if (!memo.length) { return memo = [...memo, [car]]; }

      let lastItem = memo[memo.length-1];

      if (lastItem.length < 2) {
        memo[memo.length-1] = [...lastItem, car];
      } else {
        memo = [...memo, [car]];
      }

      return memo;
    }, []);
```

Then in your template loop through the rows and cars:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of carRows" class="row">
      <app-car *ngFor="let car of row" [car]="car">
        ...
```